# Installing apc on XAMPP 1.7.4

Tags: xampp

i'm new here. Oftentimes i will just search through google and get the answers right away except this one. I'm sorry for my question (if you are not liking it) as I am new to forums like this.

What i want to do is to install apc.dll to XAMPP 1.7.4 so i will download the file that should be here: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1.5-5.3-vc6-x86.zip but its not there. Somebody can provide me the right link?

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download dll from http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc/sorting//1.html
did work for me on window7 64 bit OS.
Copy the dll on the php/ext directory of xampp 1.7.4, rename the dll file to php_apc.dll
and add extension = php_apc.dll to your php.ini file.